# Convex N-sided polygon color problem.

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving a question to find number of ways in which the corners of a square can be colored with two colors. I got the answer 6. I extended the question as follows. Vertices are unlabelled.

- Numbers of ways in which the corners of an n-sided polygon can be colored with two colors? (It is permissible to use a single color on all n corners.)
- Numbers of ways in which the corners of an n-sided polygon can be colored with m colors? (It is permissible to use a single color on all n corners.)

Now, I am unable to solve any of these questions. Can anyone provide solution please? (If not complete, partial solution or hints). Thanks.

Comment: I assume that you can use rotation to show that two colorings are really the same?

Comment: Yes, @Bram28 Vertices are unlabelled.

Comment: Did you try and search for the answer to this? ... I assume it is a well known problem.

Comment: Oh, I don't know whether it is well known or not. I was just solving circular combinations & permutations. Still couldn't solve this. @Bram28

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring ... though it looks like they rule out adjacent vertices having the same colors.  Still, maybe a good starting point for how to think about this problem .. or further references.